# The definition of Null set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

The definition of A is a Null set is that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$,forall $\varepsilon>0$, exists open cover $\{I_n\}$,so that
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty |I_n|\leq \varepsilon.$

Could I change open intervals set to close intervals set?

I think the essence of the question is how to define the length of interval?

For example, we define the length of close interval $[a,b]$ is $b-a.$If also define the length of open interval $(a,b)$ is $b-a$,obviously,two definition is equivalent.

Besides,how to define the length of$(a,b],[a,b)$?Is there have well-defined?

Comment: If $a,b$ are real numbers with $a<b$, then the Borel measure of the intervals $(a,b), (a,b], [a,b), [a,b]$ is the same and is equal to $b-a$. The Borel measure of the single point set $\{x\}$ is $0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Michael I presume you meant Lebesgue measure? Borel measures refer to a class of measures, not all of which are atomless.

Comment: If your definition specifies a *countable* open cover, then changing from open to closed won't matter.

Comment: @DavidGao : Thanks. The terminology here gets confusing. I mean the standard measure on the standard Borel sigma algebra on the real number line, the one that maps intervals to their length. =) I did not want to consider the completion of the Borel sigma algebra so I did not want Lebesgue meaure. My measurable space is $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the sigma algebra generated by $(-\infty, x]$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0, \infty]$ is the unique measure with $\mu((a,b))=b-a$.

Comment: @Michael Ah, well, maybe just say Lebesgue measure restricted to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra? I don’t think there’s a specific name for this, as usually people don’t try to explicitly avoid taking completions. Borel measures would refer to all measures defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (and by a slight abuse of notations, measures obtained from completing those). I should also note the definition of null sets the OP posted in the question is actually that of null sets in the (completed) Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @DavidGao Compositions of measurable functions are measurable, and this gets tangled up when we start using Lebesgue instead of Borel. =)

Comment: @Michael That’s certainly true. The usual definition of measurable functions features an asymmetry since the codomain is generally understood as equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Usually people distinguished this by calling measurable functions w.r.t. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the domain as Borel functions. So you still can compose measurable functions with Borel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|\cdot|$ is a nonnegative measure that acts on a sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ that includes all intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, and that satisfies for all real numbers $a,b$ with $a<b$:
$$ |[a,b]| = b-a$$
Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\{x\} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[x, x+1/n]$ (so $\{x\}$ is in the sigma algebra) and for any positive integer $n$ we have
$$ \{x\} \subseteq [x, x+1/n] \implies |\{x\}|\leq \underbrace{|[x,x+1/n]|}_{1/n}$$
Taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ in the above gives $|\{x\}|=0$, which holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This means for all real numbers $a,b$ with $a<b$:
$$b-a=|[a,b]| = \underbrace{|\{a\}|}_{0} + |(a,b)| + \underbrace{|\{b\}|}_{0} = |(a,b)|$$
Similarly
$$|[a,b)| = |\{a\}| + |(a,b)| = 0 + (b-a)=b-a$$
$$|(a,b]| = |(a,b)| + |\{b\}| = b-a + 0 = b-a$$

---

Therefore, if you have a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a sequence of open intervals  $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (of the type $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$ for $a_n<b_n$) such that $A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |I_n|\leq \epsilon$, then you can define closed intervals $\hat{I}_n=[a_n,b_n]$ and, since $|I_n|=|\hat{I}_n|$ for all $n$, we immediately have $A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \hat{I}_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\hat{I}_n|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |I_n|\leq \epsilon$.

Conversely, Suppose you have a set  $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a sequence of closed intervals  $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (of the type $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ for $a_n<b_n$) such that $A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |I_n|\leq \epsilon$. Then for any $\delta>0$ you can define open intervals $\tilde{I}_n=(\tilde{a}_n, \tilde{b}_n)$ such that $A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \tilde{I}_n$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\tilde{I}_n|\leq \delta$$
I leave to you as an exercise to construct such $\tilde{I}_n$. (Hint: Define $\epsilon = \delta/2$.)

**This means:** Assuming your $I_n$ sets in your definition of "null set" are open intervals, then you can indeed change $I_n$ to be closed intervals and the corresponding new definition is equivalent to the old.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! For exercise:Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{2^n}=1,$So construct $\overline{I}=(a_n+\delta\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}},b_n-\delta\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}})$ and then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\overline{I}|\leq \delta,$Did I right?

Comment: I was thinking slightly different, so $\tilde{I}_n$ is larger (rather than smaller) than $[a_n,b_n]$ so that we can be sure $A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\tilde{I}_n$. So I would use $\tilde{I}_n=(a_n - \epsilon/2^{n+1}, b_n + \epsilon/2^{n+1})$ so the extra amount we add does not exceed $\epsilon$.